# Set default value for SharePoint Calendar description field

Tags: powershell, calendar

How can you set the default value for the 'Description' field for a SharePoint 2010 calendar list? There is nothing in the web interface for doing this, so I have tried it with PowerShell.

```
$w = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://SPSite
$l = $w.Lists["My Calendar"]
$f = $l.Fields["Description"]
$f.DefaultValue = "default value"
$f.Update()
```

It runs without any exceptions occurring, but does not set the default value.

I want to include some text in the description field that shows when adding a new event via SharePoint or Outlook 2010.

Comment: Did @James [script on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/nvXpWC3J) help you here? Accepting answers helps motivate people to answer your questions as reputation is awarded.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll get the default value to show in Outlook when creating an event. Also, try setting the default value to the Site Column called Description and call `Update(true)`.

Comment: I get an exception if I pass true: `$f.Update( <<<< true)
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (CloseParenToken:TokenId) [], ParentContainsErro
rRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall`

Comment: I did put the closing bracket in... even using `$TRUE` instead of `true` does not work (but prevents the exception from occurring)

Comment: Might need to pass "True". PoSH still evades me to this day :)

Comment: That doesn't help either...

Comment: The hell? Hmm, if anyone else is good at PoSH, this is the method I'm trying to see if it works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454698.aspx - in the mean time, let me try on my VM

Comment: This worked for me: http://pastebin.com/nvXpWC3J

Comment: Would you mind pasting your PasteBin script into your answer? Then we don't lose it. :)